# eg: I would want to write an xpath that would click an element based on the input value

Tags: android, xpath, robotframework

Below is the element for which I am trying to write an XPath

`<div class="displayInlineBlock Roman30Px_New bsbAccountFont ng-binding">123456</div>`

The above element is many on the page and one can distinguish using the value which is at the end i.e. 123456.

XPath I tried was this way and on trying I found that there was an innerText that holds the value 123456.

`//*[@class='displayInlineBlock Roman30Px_New bsbAccountFont ng-binding']`

I am not sure how to make this element get clicked for each specific value I enter.
Few other ways i tried was

`xpath=from_frst_part=//div[innerText='123456'']/innerText`

but nothing worked.

Another way I was thinking is finding the number of elements on the page and get attribute but I felt it was long and cumbersome.

Comment: I finally found the solution as well thought I answer it incase if it might be helpful for someone xpath=//div[@class='displayInlineBlock Roman30Px_New bsbAccountFont ng-binding'][text()='123456']

Comment: Please put it into an answer that you can accept as well, effectively closing the question.

Answer (score 0):

i think a suitable xpath could also be as so, by using the `and` keyword instead of separating the attributes to individual brackets:
`//div[@class='displayInlineBlock Roman30Px_New bsbAccountFont ng-binding' and text()='123456']`